Notifying a change in SwiftData @query
I have a SwiftData @Query which gives me a array of Event objects.
Due to the nature of the object (e.g. dynamic distance calculations) I filter the events manually using function.
This works fine for any changes in the objects, and they are shown directly in the SwiftUI List. But If I add an object the List is not updated (as it is created from the filtered list, not directly from the @Quary).
Is there a way to subscribe to the @Quary to get a notification (or to pass the state on) so the data is refreshed? This is the relevant code, the data variable contains the data sorted by day and filtered using a normal function. FilterManager is an observable object, which notifies if the filter parameters change.
@State var data: [Date:[Event]] = [:]
@Query(sort: \Event.startTime) private var events: [Event]

List {
   ForEach(Array(data.keys).sorted(by: <), id: \.self) { day in
         Section(header: Text(day,format: Date.FormatStyle()
              .year(.defaultDigits)
              .month(.abbreviated)
              .day(.twoDigits)
              .weekday(.abbreviated)).font(.footnote)) {
                   ForEach(data[day]!) { item in
                          [...]
                   }
         }
 }.onAppear(){
    data = filterManager.sortedEvents(events: filterManager.filteredEvents(events: events))
 }.onReceive(filterManager.objectWillChange){
    data = filterManager.sortedEvents(events: filterManager.filteredEvents(events: events))
 }


you could try using a computed property, such as var data: [Date:[Event]] { filterManager.sortedEvents(events: filterManager.filteredEvents(events: events)) } instead of @State var data...

That did the trick, and it works perfect now

turned the comment into an answer.

Just be aware that a computed property that relies on a @Query property will be called a lot so this could lead to performance issues depending on what is being done in those sort and filter functions and of course on how much data you have.

id: \.self will probably cause a crash since its not a valid keypath to unique identifier. Also onReceive isn't right, SwiftUI already monitors observable objects automatically.

FYI @Query takes a filter param, can only be a static filter in the current version though. Should let you remove the need for onAppear, onReceive and filterManager.

Use a computed property (that depends on events), such as
var data: [Date:[Event]] { 
   filterManager.sortedEvents(events: filterManager.filteredEvents(events: events)) 
} 

instead of
@State var data: [Date:[Event]] = [:]


Assuming you add Event objects which trigger a refresh of the Query, you should be able to observe it:
.onChange(of: events.count) {
    data = filterManager.sortedEvents(events: filterManager.filteredEvents(events: events))
}

